# DAX expression to get the intersection of two sets

Tags: action, dax

Example scenario: find courses that have at least a Canadian and an American student, given an enrollment table Enrol(CourseId, StudentId, ...) and a student table Student(StudentId, nationality, ...).

I defined a rowset action that use the following DAX expression to get the course ids,

```
evaluate (
    intersect(
        calculatetable(
            summarize('Enrol','Enrol'[CourseId])
            , <Filter 1>        
        )
        ,
        calculatetable(
            summarize('Enrol','Enrol'[CourseId])
           , <Filter 2>
        )
    )
)
```

but this does not work. I looked up the documentation for [intersect operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243783.aspx) , and it looks like I must be missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated. Expressions below

```
evaluate (
    calculatetable(
        summarize('Enrol','Enrol'[CourseId])
        , <Filter 1>        
    )
)
```

when evaluated separately, does give the result set that I want. Somehow a simple intersection would always lead to the error saying

```
Executing the query ...
Query (1, 10) This is not a valid DAX expression.
Execution complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ae8973ad-b066-419b-90f3-11e7f225331e/equivalent-of-tsqls-if-exists-in-dax?forum=sqlanalysisservices), finally the problem is solved with nested CalculateTable() functions.

```
evaluate (
    CalculateTable(
        Summarize('Enrol','Enrol'[CourseId]),
        CalculateTable(
            Values('Enrol'[CourseId]),
            <Filter 1>
        ),
        <Filter 2>
    )
)
```

This pattern applies to any 1:M relationship where you need to find entities at the 1 side that matches multiple conditions at the many side. Another example could be finding orders with multiple items specified.

It is perhaps also worth noting that I've tried to use contains function to solve that problem too:

```
evaluate (
    calculatetable(
        'Courses'
        , contains(
            RelatedTable('Enrol') 
            ,'Enrol'[StudentId]
            ,<StudentId for Canadians>
        )
        , contains(
            RelatedTable('Enrol') 
            ,'Enrol'[StudentId]
            ,<StudentId for Americans>
        )
    )
)
```

This solution failed with the error

```
A function 'MINX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a     table filter expression. This is not allowed.
```

Well I have no idea what `MINX` has to do here. The same error was reported in the post above.

I know it's a pain to debug rowset action MDX expressions. Here's the full rowset action expression I ended up using (yes I used Marco's [Basket Analysis pattern](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2014/06/12/basket-analysis-with-dax-in-powerpivot-and-ssas-tabular.aspx) to build the cube),

```
"
Evaluate(
    CalculateTable(
        Summarize('Enrol','Enrol'[CourseId]),
        CalculateTable(
        Values('Enrol'[CourseId])
        ,'Enrol'[StudentId] = " + {Existing [Student Filter].[StudentId].[StudentId].Members}.Item(0).Name +
        "),
        'Enrol'[StudentId] = " + {Existing [Students].[StudentId].[StudentId].Members}.Item(0).Name +
    ")
)"
```